# Does the PS4 come with 14 days free membership out-of-the-box?

Tags: psn, ps4, playstation-plus

Does the Play Station 4 come with 14 days free membership included?

I cannot see anything on the PS website and it is not mentioned in this [video](http://www.engadget.com/2013/11/11/sony-playstation-4-unboxing/).

If not, I understand 90 day and 365 day subscriptions can be purchased. Do these come as a code that can be added to any (old and new) accounts?

To give some scope, I'm looking at buying 90 subscription of Playstation Plus for my Bro for Christmas so he can play COD online, providing my answers are confirmed above.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken: If you buy PS+ over the PSN, there is no code to redeem and PS+ will be unlocked for the account you bought it from. If you buy PS+ retail, it'll be in form of a redeemable code usable on any account.

Comment: It may vary by region. My US launch PS4 came with a code for a 30-day free PS Plus trial, but I have no idea how to answer this question for other regions, or whether future production runs of the PS4 will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the included membership, but PS+ Physical cards are codes to redeem in the PS Store. You may also purchase it via credit card on his account directly to have it applied to that account.

Comment: Ah ok. I guess it doesn't include free membership. I only ask because it's something xBox do. Excellent, thanks for posting.

Comment: Yeah Im an Xbox user so I know that much as well, but it may be given on a new account creation on new system basis.

Answer (score 0):

The PS4 comes with codes for a 30-day trial membership, 30-day Music Unlimited membership, and $10 Store Credit. They are contained with the printed materials inside the box.

Comment: What region are you in? What Source? You may merge into my answer if you have these.

Comment: All right. I merged my answer and added credit card requirements for free offers that were included just to be thorough. I got my PS4 during launch for NA. I can't say any other waves will contain that, but the expiration dates on the included cards are march of 2014.

Answer (score 0):

I just bought a ps4  but did not come with 30 day trial for PS+   only 10$ PS store money and 30 day unlimited music redeem codes

Comment: I observed the same - bought a PS4 today and got no free trial for PS+, but did get the music unlimited and PS store $10. I guess Sony adjusted it.